# PHP creating a png image

Tags: php, image

I am trying to create a PHP image, although I have come across some problems.
I am trying to add a URL to the php file. The url (global.php) contains information to grab the Username of a specific user and input certain image files into the php image.

But whenever I add the global.php link, the image won't show up.
My main question is, am I able to add links to files, plus add things like echo ' ' ; to the php image file?

```
    <?php
// MySQL Connect & Select
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password') or die('Error connecting to mysql');
mysql_select_db('database');

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".stripslashes(trim(htmlspecialchars(mysql_real_escape_string(mysql_escape_string($_GET['user'])))))."'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$result_stats = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_stats WHERE id = '".$row['id']."'") or die("USER_STATS: ".mysql_error());
$row_stats = mysql_fetch_array($result_stats);
$result_info = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE user_id = '".$row['id']."'") or die("USER_INFO: ".mysql_error());
$row_info = mysql_fetch_array($result_info);

$text[1] = "Hiya, ".$row['username']."!";
$text[2] = "Your last login was ".@date("d-M-Y\n H:i",$row['last_online']).". We missed you :)";
$text[3] = "Do you know the Rare! Way";
$text[4] = "".$row['username']."?";
$text[5] = "I do!";
$text[6] = "Be sure to follow the Rare! Way. \n \n When you follow the Way, you're giving \n yourself the best experience on Rare! that you \n can ever get! Stay tuned for more.";

// Colors
$image      = imagecreatefrompng('userbanner/hotel.png');
$black      = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
$white      = imagecolorallocate($image, 250, 250, 250);
$grey       = imagecolorallocate($image, 77, 77, 77);

// Font
$volterB    = 'userbanner/Ubuntu-B.ttf';
$volder     = 'userbanner/Ubuntu-M.ttf';
$conden     = 'userbanner/Ubuntu-L.ttf';
$light      = 'userbanner/Ubuntu-Regular.ttf';


$userimage1 = imagecreatefrompng("http://www.habbo.com/habbo-imaging/avatarimage?figure=".$row['look']."&direction=2&head_direction=2&gesture=spk&img_format=png");
imagecopy($image, $userimage1, 420, 288, 0, 0, 64, 110);




$userimage  = imagecreatefrompng("http://www.habbo.com/habbo-imaging/avatarimage?figure=".$row['look']."&direction=2&head_direction=2&gesture=sml&img_format=png");
imagecopy($image, $userimage, 220, 628, 0, 0, 64, 110);

// Create image from text
imagettftext($image, 15, 0, 20, 465, $black, $volterB, $text[1]);
imagettftext($image, 8, 0, 20, 483, $black, $conden, $text[2]);
imagettftext($image, 18, 0, 510, 300, $black, $volterB, $text[3]);
imagettftext($image, 15, 0, 510, 330, $black, $volterB, $text[4]);
imagettftext($image, 15, 0, 345, 333, $black, $volder, $text[5]);
imagettftext($image, 10, 0, 520, 360, $grey, $light, $text[6]);
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($image);
imagedestroy($image);



?>
```

If I've been unclear in any way, please let me know. Thanks :)

Comment: You should be able to use a URL in imagecreatefrompng.  First make sure you don't have any whitespace before and after the PHP tags.  To debug, put ob_start(); on the first line and file_put_contents('/tmp/wtf', ob_get_clean()) at the very end.  Check /tmp/wtf to see the output, if any.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem though, is that when I add the global.php line into the file, the image doesn't show. Otherwise it does. Global.php includes links that are used throughout the whole website though.

Comment: Don't worry. Fixed the problem, thanks for your help :)